# How can I select first element from each of child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

In following html code, how can I select element a for 'Item 2_1', 'Item 3_1', ...

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2_3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2_4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3_2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: both solutions below are correct given this html, but your surrounding markup will have to decide which way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
$('ul li ul li:first-child a');
```

should do the Job

Answer (score 5):

```
$('li ul li:first-child a');
```

We select the second level `ul`'s (`li ul`), and then select the first `li` of each of them, and retrieve the `a` within it.